# C# send alt key and hold

Tags: c#, windows-10, alt

how can I send the alt key press and holding countionusly while the mouse moving?

```
Thread.Sleep(100);
SendKeys.Send("%"); // Should be command to hold // How here make this to hold till the next below the for loop?

for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
{
    Thread.Sleep(10);
    this.Cursor = new Cursor(Cursor.Current.Handle);
    Cursor.Position = new Point(Cursor.Position.X - 1 * i, Cursor.Position.Y - 1 * i);
}

SendKeys.Send("%"); // Here should release.
```

Important that I want to do it in Windows 10.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: What's purpose ALT key?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SendKeys.SendWait("%");` [(MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.sendwait(v=vs.110).aspx) instead. Should work fine on Windows 10.